# SurveyMonkey: API for Enterprise Apps

Tags: surveymonkey

I want to know if there is any API available for the enterprise version of Surveymonkey.

I wish to get all the info available to the Admin for an enterprise app through API (json data)

I believe the Admin functionality is accessible only through the Interface(UI) and I haven't come across any mention of it in the API at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/

Is there any REST API for this admin user(that could give me all the data for that enterprise)? If yes, does it provide the following data?

1) Get all users (of the enterprise)

2) User's information (survey data, account/activity logs etc.)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some Enterprise data available through the API. You didn't find it in the docs because it was released last week and the docs haven't been updated yet. get_user_details returns:

**data.is_enterprise_user** `Boolean`

Returns if the account is a SurveyMonkey Enterprise account

**data.enterprise_details.total_seats_invoiced** `Integer`

The number of seats purchased for this enterprise account

**data.enterprise_details.total_seats_active** `Integer`

The number of seats currently being used by this enterprise account

It's not currently possible to get a list of Enterprise users even from the Enterprise Admin's account, but I expect it will in the future. Detailed information about user's surveys and other account information is not accessible to Enterprise admins even through the user interface. To get access to a user's SurveyMonkey account, you will need to request authorization from each user using OAuth and then access their accounts individually.

For reference: [SurveyMonkey Enterprise: Data Ownership](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/SurveyMonkey-Enterprise-Data-Ownership)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony! Btw, when do they plan on releasing these features if they ever do(any time-frame)?

Comment: It's very hard to say when features will be released. We set deadlines and we try very hard to make them happen, but priorities can change, unexpected challenges can be presented, and resources can become constrained by other means. The best answer I can give with any confidence is "Watch the docs for updates"